# module.exports.variable_name directly behavior

Tags: javascript

look at this example:

```
const a = 5
module.exports.a = a;
let b = "foo"
module.exporta.b = b
```

if we export this variables . in everywhere a variable is const and b variable is  let .what about this example :

```
module.exports.c = "bar"
```

what is this? a var type? let? const? I mean  javascript engine treat this to what? I am getting wrong definition or behavior of javascript or this is a correct question that came to my mind?

Comment: `a variable is const and b variable is let`. Yes, the _variables_ are, but that has nothing to do with the _members_ `a` and `b` on `module.exports`. They're both writable, as is the member `c` assigned the string literal.

Comment: so when we declear c . javascript is not considering that is a variable we asigned to a string value?

Comment: now I get it when we export something its considered of module.exports property so we can change it every where as what we want . suppose we have cont a in a example.js file . we can declare that in another file as a let a . so that has nothing to do with that const a . tnx for reply . I dont know why people giving me a negative point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` and `let` are for defining variables. Things in `module.exports` are properties of an object (that object being `module.exports`), and so they are controlled by their [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Whether or not the value is mutable is controlled by the `writable` descriptor field. It no longer has a scope of its own, it can be accessed wherever its parent can. You can't really think of them like a `let` or `const`.

Since in Javascript, arguments are passed by value, in this:

```
let b = "foo"
module.exports.b = b
```

After this code is executed, `module.exports.b` has nothing to do with the variable `b`. It's not a `let`, or a `const` it's just a property of `module.exports`. You could change the value of `b` and it would have no effect on `module.exports.b`.

Comment: Actually all assignments and parameters in JavaScript are pass by value. It's just that objects are reference types, so they appear to be pass by reference when in fact they're not.

Comment: **for reference, but answer is now correct** Passing objects does not act similar to "pass by reference" in other languages. What I meant to say is that they're simply misattributed as "pass by reference" when in fact they don't behave that way at all. To clarify what I mean, say you have `var a = { foo: 'bar' }; function f (b) { b = { hello: 'world' }; } f(a); console.log(a);`. If objects were pass by reference, `a` would be `{ hello: 'world' }` but because they're pass by value, the reference isn't overwritten in the function body

Comment: Removed for clarity

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing `module.exports.a = 'a'`, you're not exporting a variable itself, you're exporting a *binding*.

Then if when importing you assigng it to const like `const {a} = require('./a')`, it will be `const`, if you import it assigning to `let {a} = require('./a')`, it will be `let`.